# Angular UI routing - Any page refresh brings me back to the index page of my web portal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, rails-routing

I am suffering this issue since the beginning of my website development. I am using rails as the backend framework. When I refresh any page, I am navigated to the index page.

For ex: if I am on www.google.com/ab/xyz/123 and I refresh, then I am navigated to www.google.com.

I am providing my angular and rails code with parameters changed due to my company's policy.

Angular routing

```
angular.module('SampleApp').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('page1', {
          url: '/page1',
          templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('page1.html') %>"
        })
        .state('page2', {
          url: '/page2',
          templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('page2.html') %>"
        })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
]);
```

Rails routing

scope '/google' do

get '/page1' => 'controller#get_page1',   :constraints => { :format => 'html' }

get '/page2' => 'controller#get_page2',   :constraints => { :format => 'html' }

## the below matches for the unknown urls

match '/*path' => redirect('/google.com'), via: :all

I would appreciate if anyone could take out some time out of you busy schedule and let me know the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your URL references are ambiguous. Please include the exact scenario which reproduces this issue. Read about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @31 I have changed the urls. However, I have given an example in my question. I cannot paste my exact code here. Hence I have written page1 and page2. Let me know if you do not understand the question. Thanks.

Comment: I understood your question, but the example is not enough to provide you with an exact working answer. Also, please format the post.

Comment: @31: I cannot copy paste my code here. I apologize for this inconvenience but I cannot give more code than this. Also, I think even if I give my template code, its of no use. We can assume that there is some page1 and page2.

Answer (score 0):

`scope '/google'` means that the URLs to page1 and page2 will be `/google/page1` and `/google/page2` respectively.

I am assuming that the line `match '/*path' => redirect('/google.com'), via: :all` is out of the `scope '/google'`.

Now, as per your statement, if you're on a URL such as www.google.com/ab/xyz/123 and refresh the page, you get redirected to www.google.com. This is the right scenario. Since your rails app doesn't support any such routes, it will match the other path and will redirect to google.com.

Why angular works? Angular router doesn't consult with Rails before routing. It just follows what you've defined as your states. That's why the URLs such as `/page1` and `/page2` will work on Angular side. But as soon as you refresh your page, the control goes back Rails, and since Rails doesn't know what that route is, it will redirect you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You are right. This issue got resolved. I entered dummy routes in the rails routes.rb file for page 1 and page 2 and captured them in the angular.js routes and redirected to the page 1 and page 2.